# Solving first-order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find all the functions in the first quadrant ($x>0,y>0$) that have the following property: the tangent to the function at $(x,y)$ intersects the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis and creates with the axes a triangle with area of $1$.
>
> *Hint*: Try to obtain a second-order differential equation from the equation you get.

*My attempt*:

The slope of the tangent line at $(x_0,y_0)$ is $f'(x_0)$, therefore the equation of the tangent is $y=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$. One of the legs of the triangle has the length $|y(0)|=|f(x_0)-f'(x_0)x_0|$ while the other leg has the length $|x_0-f(x_0)/f'(x_0)|$. Therefore the condition is:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left|\left( f(x_0)-f'(x_0)x_0\right) \left(x_0-\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}\right)\right|=1$$

This must be true for all the points $(x_0,y_0)$, so we arrive at the differential equation:

$$(y-xy')(x-y/y')=2$$

I have no idea how to solve it. I was trying to use the hint and do some substitution that will give me a second-order DE but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Re-writing your ODE as $$-(y-xy')^2 = 2y' \quad \cdots \cdots \: (*)$$

Differentiate one more time:

\begin{align*}
  -2(y-xy')(y'-y'-xy'') &= 2y'' \\
  2xy''(y-xy') &= 2y'' \\
  x(y-xy') &= 1 \quad \quad (y'' \ne 0) \\
  \frac{y}{x^2}-\frac{y'}{x} &= \frac{1}{x^3} \\
  \left( -\frac{y}{x} \right)' &= \frac{1}{x^3} \\
  \frac{y}{x} &= -\int \frac{dx}{x^3} \\
  \frac{y}{x} &= \frac{1}{2x^2}+C \\
  y &= Cx+\frac{1}{2x}
\end{align*}

Now $y'=C-\dfrac{1}{2x^2}$ and substitute into $(*)$ that gives $C=0$.

> So the curve is hyperbola $$2xy=1$$

**N.B.**

- The mid-point of the intercepts is the contact point itself.
- $y''=0$ gives a trivial solution $y=Ax+B$ where $B=\sqrt{-2A}$.

Comment: Thank you, this indeed solves the equation. But according to Wolfram there are also solutions of the form $y(x)=\frac{2C-x}{2C^2}$ (i.e. linear). How can we obtain them?

Comment: I guess Wolfram Alpha giving the omitted solution $y''=0$, i.e. $y=Ax+B$ where $-B^2=2A$ which is a straight line.